# Failed to apply plugin [class 'FlutterPlugin'] after updating android studio

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I had just updated Android Studio and the new version details:
[image]

I get an error when I build my project

When I **build** or **sync** my project I get the same error, before the `Failed to apply plugin [class 'FlutterPlugin']` error, I got another error that I need to mention `flutter.sdk` in `local.properties` and I mentioned it, then I get the error. But there are **2 errors and not one, I think they both are together** so if one is **fixed** the other will be **fixed** too.

You can see the errors below:

Error 1

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin [class 'FlutterPlugin']
```

Error 2

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method register() for arguments [generateLockfiles, FlutterPlugin$_apply_closure1@545cc796] on task set of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.
```

Local.properties (I hope it helps)

```
## This file must *NOT* be checked into Version Control Systems,
# as it contains information specific to your local configuration.
#
# Location of the SDK. This is only used by Gradle.
# For customization when using a Version Control System, please read the
# header note.
#Wed Feb 16 16:11:58 GST 2022
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\osedk\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
flutter.sdk=C\:\\Users\\osedk\\Documents\\flutter\\flutter
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: writing everything in bold will most likely result in people not even reading the question, it just looks horrible, no need to go that far with your formatting, keep it simple

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestion, I made some edits, do you have any idea to fix this error ? Thank you @a_local_nobody